# Prove the solution to PDE problem is the trivial

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$$u_t = c^2u_{xx} \mid (x,t) \in (0,L) \times (0, \infty)$$
$$u_x(0,t) = u_x(L,t) = 0 \mid t > 0$$
$$u(x,0) = 0 \mid x \in [0,L]$$

---

I tried energy method based on Pinchover and Rubinstein (*):

$$\text{Let } E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{L} u^2 dx$$

$$\to E'(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{L} 2uu_t dx$$

$$= c^2 \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{L} 2uu_{xx} dx$$

$$= c^2 \int_{0}^{L} uu_{xx} dx$$

$$= c^2 [\underbrace{uu_{x}\mid_{0}^{L}}_{\text{zero}} - \int_{0}^{L} u_x dx] \text{(**)}$$

$$= - c^2 [\int_{0}^{L} u_x dx]$$

I'm suppose to say that $E(t)$ is nonnegative, decreasing and zero when $t=0$, but I think I'm missing another $u_x$ in the integrand in the last line:

---

(**)

$$\int_{0}^{L} uu_{xx} dx$$

$$ w = u \mid dv = u_{xx} dx$$

$$dw = du \mid v = u_{x}$$

$$= uu_{x} - \int_{0}^{L} u_{x} dx$$

Is it supposed to be that $dw = u_x dx$?

---

Where did I go wrong? Any other mistakes?

---

(*)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you even read all these pages included as images? 'Cause they explicitely state that $$\int uu_{xx}dx=uu_x-\int (u_{x})^2dx,$$ and certainly not your version $$\int uu_{xx}dx=uu_x-\int u_{x}dx,$$ whose origin remains a mystery.

Comment: @Did So it's supposed to be $dw = u_xdx$?

Comment: Suggestion: Read what the tags (differential-equations), (physics) and (mathematical-physics) are about, before using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to be $dw = u_xdx$ because the differentiation is w/rt x and not u, like how the integration for the dv part is w/rt x